# Planning Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, deployment

I've been tasked to prepare Azure SQL database deployment plan and I am struggling with it...

I've been given following information:

1. 2 million transactions will arrive to database daily throughout the day (~278 tr/sec on average).
2. Transactions will arrive from 1000 different locations (onprem SQL Servers generating 2000 transactions daily each)
3. All transactions will have a fixed size of 12KB. Therefore I am expecting to get about about 22-23 GB of data daily.
4. All data will be regularly aggregated and accessed from 100 different locations for BI purposes.
5. Updated data (configurations) will be sent back to aforementioned 1000 locations

I've tried to use Azure SQL DTU calculator, but it requires to run PowerShell script on existing server and I don't have one... This a new system, that is currently in development and it is planned to run on Azure SQL.

I also tried to find the way to convert transactions to DTU or Vcore, but failed to find any.

Can anyone please help me with that? Or point me in to right direction to choose correct plan to suffice my needs based on info provided.

Thank you in advance.
Mike

Comment: Have you worked with Azure before?  The only advice I can give you here is to not underestimate your I/O requirements.  But you may want to go back and get more information.  These incoming transactions, what are they?  The aggregate queries, what are they doing?

Comment: Honestly, get a consultant. Any answers posted here in this complex situation are likely to be inadequate. Maybe even dangerous. Get someone in with real experience who can guide you through this. That's the best approach. Personally, for this one, I'd recommend Denny Cherry & Associates. They know this space extremely well.

Comment: Thank you guys.... You've just confirmed my suspicions that i don't have enough data... Sorry i can't elaborate more on that as this is development in progress project and it's still hush-hush kinda thing. But I am pretty sure, devs will have to share much more info before i can even remotely assess the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Easy!

Use the [Azure SQL Database DTU Calculator](http://dtucalculator.azurewebsites.net/):

1. Download the PowerShell script on your server
2. Run `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\sql-perfmon.ps1` and let it run for a few minutes
3. On the web page enter the number of cores that your server is using
4. Stop the PowerShell script and upload the .CSV file that is now on the C:\ root

[image]

Comment: This works great for an existing system you are migrating... but this is greenfield work (as the OP mentioned).

Comment: You are right. From my understanding, as he has no access to the server those 5 points he mentioned are enough to choose. There is no extra work to do in my opinion. The question is the answer